# Raspbian Wheezy: Kernel Panic in Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, kernel, raspberry-pi, raspbian, panic

I have been busy installing the operating system (Raspbian Wheezy), I managed to follow all the instructions and get the Raspberry Pi working etc. However then when I turned it off and sometime later restarted (first time it had been turned on after the installation had finished and was working) I got the following

> error: Kernel Panic - not syncing: No init found.

I have googled the error and found many references to Kernel Panic but usually with a different error message. Is this still likely to be an issue with the SD card?

Answer (score 2):

Apologies for a partial answer, but it seems like this is still early in the troubleshooting process. Some people have had success reseating the SD card (like up to 20 times). I created two SD cards yesterday, one with 2015-01-31 Raspbian and another with Snappy Unbuntu Core. At first neither would boot my brand new Raspberry Pi 2. Somewhere in the process of swapping out the cards and rebooting (and reimaging the cards) I made progress: I now consistently get a kernel panic with Raspbian but I can boot and log into Snappy Unbuntu. So I suppose I can add some credence to the reseating of the SD card.

Others report success writing an SD card with an earlier image and then doing an apt-get update, but sadly this is not an option with the RPi 2 as it cannot boot on anything but the latest Raspbian.

A little more information and discussion can be found here:
http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=98856&p=686398